# Impersonation does not work in Microsoft Dynamics CRM - SYSTEM user is always used

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, impersonation, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-365

I am investigating impersonation in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 / Dynamics 365 organization service and I found that the code is always executed on behalf of the system user (SYSTEM).

I created a plugin that should execute requests on behalf of different users:

- system user (SYSTEM)
- default user
- user specified in the plugin registration tool
- user initiating the request

But the code is always executed on behalf of the system user (SYSTEM).

I tried not only to display an exception, but also to create records - they are also created on behalf of the system user (SYSTEM).

```
public class GetUsers : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        var factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));

        var result = "";

        var service1 = factory.CreateOrganizationService(null);
        result += $"null = {GetUserInfo(service1)}";

        var service2 = factory.CreateOrganizationService(Guid.Empty);
        result += $"Guid.Empty ({Guid.Empty}) = {GetUserInfo(service2)}";

        var service3 = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
        result += $"UserId ({context.UserId}) = {GetUserInfo(service3)}";

        var service4 = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);
        result += $"InitiatingUserId ({context.InitiatingUserId}) = {GetUserInfo(service4)}";

        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(result);
    }

    private static string GetUserInfo(IOrganizationService service)
    {
        var request = new WhoAmIRequest();
        var response = (WhoAmIResponse)service.Execute(request);
        var userId = response.UserId;
        var user = service.Retrieve("systemuser", userId, new ColumnSet("fullname"));
        var data = $"{userId} | {user.GetAttributeValue<string>("fullname")}{Environment.NewLine}";
        return data;
    }
}
```

I get this result:

```
null = 34248a5f-bf3e-4f3c-95c2-882424d25d37 | SYSTEM
Guid.Empty (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) = 34248a5f-bf3e-4f3c-95c2-882424d25d37 | SYSTEM
UserId (0a889533-cf85-e811-a21b-d47c6ef71c14) = 34248a5f-bf3e-4f3c-95c2-882424d25d37 | SYSTEM
InitiatingUserId (c69c88fb-4e41-e811-a214-83daa2756e35) = 34248a5f-bf3e-4f3c-95c2-882424d25d37 | SYSTEM
```

All requests are executed on behalf of the system user, although they must on behalf of different users.

Previously (in CRM 4.0-2013) it worked, but now it does not work. I tried on two different systems (different versions) - the result is the same.

Why?

Comment: [Impersonation in plug-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg309416%28v%3dcrm.8%29)

Comment: This article talks about impersonation, but does not answer the question why all requests are executed on behalf of SYSTEM.

Answer (score 0):

Your example executes the `WhoAmI` request on behalf of several identities, but `WhoAmI` always returns the `systemuserid` of the authenticated user and since plugins are being executed by the SYSTEM account, its ID will always be returned.

Execute e.g. a `Create` request on entity Account and examine the attributes `CreatedBy`, `CreatedOnBehalf` and `OwnerId`.

Comment: You read my question inattentively. I wrote that I tried to create records - they are also created on behalf of the system user (SYSTEM). Мore precisely `CreatedBy` and `OwnerId` = SYSTEM, `CreatedOnBehalf` = Initiating User

Comment: You are not showing the code creating the records, so I cannot comment on that. D365 still works the way it's documented. Is this an OnPremise deployment? Are other plugins and/or workflows active?

Comment: This is an OnPremise deployment. No other plugins or workflow. The code for creating a record is exactly the same as I showed, but instead of calling the `WhoAmI` method, the method of `Create` is called.